# Structuring CSS files in React with Webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I'd like to get a better understanding on how I can structure my css files. My folder structure is like so:

```
-app
|-src
||-components
|||-app.js
||-styles
|||-styles.scss
|-webpack.config
```

So I have one stylesheet that will be imported  into app.js and cascade to my other components. But as I'm creating more components, my stylesheet is getting pretty long. Is it best practice to have stylesheets per component? Also, I'm using webpack to compile and extract my stylesheet into a css file to import into index.html file. If I have multiple files, I'm assuming webpack will compile all of them into one css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your application scales it becomes hard to maintain a huge CSS file , not to mention class name collision , so files separation its generally a good idea.
I prefer CSS file per page , kind of up to you how to separate them.
As for webpack loaders , think of it as a pipe , the pipe sets rule that every file that ends with .css comes in and bundled, so  yea , it will bundle multiple css files.